# How to create a new/update existing related entity on Create/Update of the main entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an object called Employee and an object called EmpDescr.

EmpDescr table has descrid and richtext. 
Employee has name, empid and descrid.

When an employee's record is being created, the form will display empname field and descr textarea. On create, the richtext will first get inserted as a new record in the empdescr table, the id will be assigned to descrid field in employee table, and then the employee record will be created.
On an update, the empdescr table will be updated and then the employee table (if required).

How can I achieve the above? I'm following the asp.net tutorials for mvc 4 and 5 and ef 5 and 6. Right now, the exact version I will use does not matter.
The tutorials have something slightly different. i.e., a list of existing courses to be added. In my case the dependent object will not exist, and it will be a single string, not a list. I'm new to MVC and EF, and am having problems getting my head around a probable solution.

I'm using database first, and not using any viewmodels.

**Edit:**
Adding to the problem here. EmpDescr is more of a general purpose table, not only related to Employee. So I will call it RichText table.
Any entity can have a richtextid that maps to this table. Adding an FK to the RichText table is out of the question because of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this.  Here is one way to go:

-Create a FK in your database for the two tables and update your EDMX.  If you can't do this, create an association without the FK.

-Don't think about what gets updated when, let EF figure that out.

-Use a EmpDescr object as your model in your create action methods.

-Display the related Employee properties through the new Employee property created in step 1.  This will allow the MVC model binder to build your entity graph.

-In your post method, don't worry about saving the Employee since it is attached to your EmpDescr it will get saved automatically.

Comment: This looks to be the right and most simplest solution. The only problem is with the correct naming and mapping of the keys.